# Is GPU version only possible for TensorFlow Object detection?

Tags: tensorflow

I make a Project using TensorFlow Object detection.
Windows might have encountered an error because of the GPU module version. Linux is trying again now. 
If you look at some review posts, it seems that GPU version has not been used. Is that right?

Comment: It is hard to understand your question, if you are asking if the TF Object Detection API supports GPU, the answer is yes.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Yes. That's the answer I'm looking for. I'm sorry to make the question difficult.